# Data request string python

Tags: python, dictionary, response

After a post request with data at a site

```
f = urllib.request.urlopen(request,data)
```

I get back a response and after

```
res = f.responce.read().decode()
```

I get a type `type(res) <class string>` that prints like:

```
[
  {
    "example": "174 55",
    "example": "example",
    "example": "example",
    "example": "",
    "example": false,
    "example": null,    
  },
  {
    "example": "174 55",
    "example": "example",
    "example": "example",
    "example": "",
    "example": false,
    "example": null,  
  }
]
```

Is there a way to get it immediately as a list of dicts, or an easy way to transform it to a list of dicts?

Comment: I doubt if you will actually have multiple `"example"` keys (same key for multiple values) and it would be `<type 'str'>` not `<class string>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is json data.

Use the built-in `json` module:

```
import json
...
res = f.responce.read().decode()
data = json.loads(res)
```